# Open website and type mismatch

Tags: inno-setup

I Want to website with ShellExec:

```
  ShellExec('open', 'http://www.domain.com/test.htm' + ErrorCode, '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

ErrorCode is int , Compiler say Type Mismatch , How can I solve This Problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an implicit cast of Int to String in InnoSetup.  You'll need to convert the data type within your code like:

```
 ShellExec('open', 'http://www.domain.com/test.htm' + IntToStr(ErrorCode), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```